# how to setup geo replication in event grid

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services, azure-eventgrid, geo-replication

In Event grid, how do we setup geo replication. as the per the documentation, it should the publisher responsibility to do the health check.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-disaster-recovery
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/geo-disaster-recovery

is there something like pairing of two resources in event grid like what is there in other services like service bus or sql database server?

Answer (score 0):

The Automatic Geo Disaster Recovery is already built-in and requires **no configuration** from your end. Do make note of the [Recovery Point Objectives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/geo-disaster-recovery#recovery-point-objective-rpo) and [Recovery Time Objectives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/geo-disaster-recovery#recovery-time-objective-rto) on guarantees made.

Considering the RPO/RTO guarantees, its best to have client-side recovery as well for maximum continuity.

Comment: I find the documentation very limited in explaining DR. What happens when there is an outage in region 1? According to the docs the metadata about the topics and so is replicated to the pair region. When a disaster happens, the pair region takes over, but does the custom topic URL to publish to also change? The URL contains a region, so I'd exect that. In that case there is a client change needed, or can we setup a load balancer with the pair region already setup?

Comment: @Jean-PaulSmit Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @Hooch there is automatic replication of metadata to the pair region. When one region has an outage, the urls will point to the fail-over region. So you have seemless fail-over there, no change of urls needed.